# Tests in subdirectory

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-tests

In Django 1.8, I have an app with this setting:

```
app
 |- tests/
 |   |- test_ook.py
 |   |- __init__.py
 |- models.py
 |- __init__.py
 ...
```

When I run `python manage.py test -v 2 app`, I get this error:

```
ImportError: 'tests' module incorrectly imported from '/home/.../site/app/tests'. Expected '/home/.../site/app'. Is this module globally installed?
```

*Why is this?*

*How can I fix it?*

Comment: Please check if you have `tests.py` or a `tests.pyc` file in the `app` i.e. at the same level as `tests` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error generally occurs if you have `tests.py` or a `tests.pyc` file present in the `app` i.e. at the same level as `tests` module.

Remove those files and it should work perfectly.